# Heroku's trying to install development gems even after I've told it not to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm diving into RoR and I'm using Heroku to host the test app I'm building.  When I do a push to Heroku, it crashes when trying to intall the linecache19 gem (which is used by ruby-debug19 gem)...

```
Installing ruby_core_source (0.1.4) 
Installing linecache19 (0.5.11) with native extensions /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
```

After searching all over the web for this problem, everyone's solution was...

```
heroku config: add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="test development" --app app_name
```

But the push to Heroku still crashes even after I did that.  Here's my Gemfile...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "fog"

group :development do
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

I even uninstalled the `ruby-debug19` gem and it's still crashing and trying to install the linecache19 gem.  Why won't this linecache19 gem go away?  I'm new to all this and, as such, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  Your thoughts?

Thanks for your wisdom!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `heroku config` command is malformed. You have a space before `add` and you are missing the colon between `development` and `test`.

`$ heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" --app app_name`

[Docs are here.](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#specifying_gems__groups)

Also, are you remembering to run `bundle install` locally and commit both your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` into `git`?

Comment: hmm that must have been a typo since heroku says Using --without development:test, but i'll try it.  also, changing that still doesn't explain to me why it's crashing even after i uninstall the gem.

Comment: nope, that didn't fix it.  still crashing when trying to install the linecache19 gem. Your thoughts?

Comment: See my edit regarding making sure that your lock file is updated.

Comment: that was it, thank you!  stupid noob mistake, i forgot to commit the changes to git.