# git push heroku failing because trying to install development gems. BUNDLE_WITHOUT command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bundler

I get an error after issuing the git push heroku command.  This initially looked like something to be solved by using the heroku config command to bundle without the development:test gems.  However, I used that command as discussed in this similar writeup [ [Heroku's trying to install development gems even after I've told it not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545450/herokus-trying-to-install-development-gems-even-after-ive-told-it-not-to) ] and it still doesn't work.

The line "Using --without development:test" in the push message below seems to indicate the BUNDLE_WITHOUT config command worked, so maybe this is a gemfile or other issue?

Thanks!

```
$ git push heroku
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (48/48), 6.03 KiB, done.
Total 48 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Installing rake (0.8.7) 
       Installing ZenTest (4.5.0) 
       Installing abstract (1.0.0) 
       Installing activesupport (3.0.3) 
       Installing builder (2.1.2) 
       Installing i18n (0.5.0) 
       Installing activemodel (3.0.3) 
       Installing erubis (2.6.6) 
       Installing rack (1.2.2) 
       Installing rack-mount (0.6.14) 
       Installing rack-test (0.5.7) 
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.25) 
       Installing actionpack (3.0.3) 
       Installing mime-types (1.16) 
       Installing polyglot (0.3.1) 
       Installing treetop (1.4.9) 
       Installing mail (2.2.15) 
       Installing actionmailer (3.0.3) 
       Installing arel (2.0.9) 
       Installing activerecord (3.0.3) 
       Installing activeresource (3.0.3) 
       Installing autotest (4.4.6) 
       Installing sys-uname (0.8.5) with native extensions 
       Installing autotest-fsevent (0.2.5) with native extensions /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

       /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
       extconf.rb:19: Only Darwin (Mac OS X) systems are supported (RuntimeError)


       Gem files will remain installed in /disk1/tmp/build_258oz7hi5972n/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.5 for inspection.
       Results logged to /disk1/tmp/build_258oz7hi5972n/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.5/ext/fsevent/gem_make.out
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/bundle:19
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler

error: hooks/pre-receive exited with error code 1
To git@heroku.com:blooming-mountain-199.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blooming-mountain-199.git'
```

Gemfile...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3', :require => 'sqlite3'

gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

gem "nokogiri"
gem "geokit"
gem "rack", "~>1.1"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc4'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'

  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-rails'
  gem 'autotest-growl'
end
```

Comment: By default, when you deploy via the heroku gem, the development and test gems are excluded; could you explain more about your setup?

Comment: I'm working through a [RoR tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) and the first few chapters went smoothly without any issues. The heroku setup is [here in section 1.4.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:1.4.1) and I'm stuck with the final deployment failing in section [3.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:static_pages_conclusion). Thanks for taking a look @JasonLewis!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the problem is clearly with the autotest-fsevent getting loaded when you push to Heroku, which is not Darwin-based. Although you do have a conditional following the `gem 'autotest-fsevent'` statement, the gem is still trying to load when you deploy to Heroku. There are two likely causes for this.

The first, is that another gem is requiring it. If nothing else, `autotest-growl` should also be Darwin-only. I'm not sure these are related, but I'd still double-check.

The next issue is to make sure that Gemfile.lock isn't getting pushed. If you last ran `bundle install` on Darwin, it's possible that the gem got locked into the dependencies that way. `git rm Gemfile.lock` before you commit and push to Heroku.

Finally, *my* favored solution is not to use autotest. I'm not sure if that's an option for you, but I found it to be annoying when I did use it I use RSpec and Cucumber. I realize this last suggestion is a non-answer, but I don't like including platform-dependent gems *even in testing,* just because when you go to staging, little annoyances like this have a tendency of cropping up.

I'm not sure why Rails Tutorial is still using ZenTest and autotest, I don't know anyone who does... that might be changing, a friend went to the Rails Tutorial session at RailsConf and said Michael was actually noting errata during the tutorial, so maybe it'll be different in a future version.

As a final note, out of curiosity, if you are on OS X, how did you install Ruby? It's in a very odd place.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!  After many attempts at Gemfile variations and gem versions, I found that Heroku doesn't support if statements in the Gemfile.  Strange, because I saw at least 30 posts across various sites suggesting the opposite.  Thanks to @helixed in [his post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288910/heroku-deployment-gemfile-lock-problem).