# Heroku Deployment Gemfile.lock Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I'm pretty new to this whole deployment thing.  I've deployed my app once before when I first created it, and everything seemed to work okay then.  I've now made some changes to my app and I'd like to deploy them and make sure they work in a production environment.  I added and committed the last of my changes and merged my changed into my master branch.  Then I ran `git push heroku master`.  I received the following error in the output:

```
Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without development:test
   You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
   the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control
```

Okay, so I need to update my gemfile.  First, I checked the contents of my `.gitignore` file, which are:

```
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3*
log/*.log
*.log
/tmp/
doc/
*.swp
*~
.project
.DS_Store
.psd
```

`Gemfile.lock` doesn't seem to be in there, but I tried the following anyway:

```
git add .
git commit -m "updated Gemfile.lock"
```

I then pushed to Heroku again and got the same error.  Next, I tried:

```
git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "updated Gemfile.lock (again)"
```

After pushing, I got the same result.  After searching around for a while, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258327/gemfile-lock-not-checked-in-heroku) post, which prompted me to try the following:

```
gem update bundler
bundle update
git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "updated Gemfile.lock (again (again))"
```

Still no luck, and I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: and you're checking into master, right?  `git status`  Can you push to github and verify that it's in your repository?  ... while I'm asking the obvious, nothing changes in your .lock file if you run a bundle install ...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it turns out the answer was pretty simple.  According to the Heroku Support Guy, you can't use if statements in your Gemfile.  The offending line from my Gemfile was:

```
gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => true if (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i)
```

Answer (score 2):

We were working Guard on both Linux and Mac, and ran into the same issue deploying Heroku. Our workaround was to install the Gem as a plugin instead of inside a conditional in the Gemfile.  In our case, the change to the Gemfile was as follows:

```
# guard
gem "growl", "~> 1.0.3"
gem "guard-coffeescript", "0.4.1"
gem "guard-sass", "0.3.3"
gem "rb-fsevent", "0.4.3.1"
gem "libnotify"
#gem "rb-inotify", "~> 0.8.8", :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
```

We then ran: `rails plugin install git://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify.git` and were good to go.

Comment: Interesting, as long as you don't forget to install the plugin on different machines.  Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Gemfile.lock file at all? It should exist at the same directory as your Gemfile.

If not, run "bundle install". That should create it.

It that still doesn't solve your problem, then I'd try to start fresh:
Clone your git repository into a new empty directory, run bundle install, run your tests, start your development server and play around - in short, make sure that everything works, then try to deploy to heroku again.

Comment: @john-benyon are you asking me or helixed?

Comment: @elad my bad...@helixed are you using Windows locally?

Comment: Sorry Elad, no luck still.  I wiped out my old application and created a new one, and I still have the same result.

Comment: @helixed sorry man, I'm out of ideas. Maybe contact Heroku's customer support?

Comment: I contacted their customer support and should get things resolved quickly.  Thanks for all the help anyway.  I appreciate it.